# Дефис в словосочетаниях типа "iOS-разработчик", "Android-разработчик"

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Нужно ли указывать дефис при написании таких словосочетаний, как `Отдел iOS разработки`, `Отдел Android разработки` и т. д.? В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81#.D0.94.D0.B5.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.81_.D0.B2_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.8C.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8) есть следующий пункт, указывающий на случай дефисного написания:

> - составные слова (горе-охотник, луна-парк, Ага-хан, генерал-майор, жар-птица, пиар-акция, киловатт-час, Санкт-Петербург, интернет-сайт, онлайн-голосование);

`iOS-разработчик`, `Android-разработчик`, по всей видимости, подходят под это правило, однако при добавлении впереди слова `отдел` складывается ощущение, что дефис более не нужен. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как писать правильно и почему.

Answer (score 3):

Дефис нужен, но причина еще более простая. Это одно слово по правилам русской грамматики (иное не стыкуется с базовыми представлениями о синтаксисе), а слитное написание слов, составленных из разных алфавитов не допускается.

Ваши примеры, конечно, тоже не противоречат этой мысли, но как прямой аргумент тут не проходят.

> однако, при добавлении впереди слова Отдел складывается ощущение

Это никакой роли, судя по всему, не играет. Скорее наоборот, именно при родовом или обобщающем слове без дефиса совсем плохо даже зрительно. Непонятно, к чему Android относится, то ли к Отделу, то ли к разработке.

Вы, возможно, спутали с кавычками, их в подобных случаях обычно опускают, если имя набрано латиницей.

Answer (score 3):

*Отдел iOS разработки, Отдел Android разработки* в дефисах не нуждаются, потому что iOS и Android - определения, стоящие впереди определяемого слова. В отличие от *iOS-разработчик, Android-разработчик*, где слово "разработчик" выступает в функции приложения. Грамота.ру по сходному поводу (на примере "флеш-карта") объясняет: это самостоятельное существительное.

См. также: [***10 слов, в которых можно ошибиться с дефисом***](http://www.mn.ru/society/edu/88481) и [***Как склонять составные существительные?***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/63-rubric-93)

> «ФЛЕШ-КАРТА» и «ФЛЕШМОБ». Возникает справедливый вопрос: почему
>   «флеш-карта» пишется через дефис, а «флешмоб» – слитно? Дело в том,
>   что слово «карта» употребляется как самостоятельное существительное, а
>   «моб» – нет. Этим объясняется разное написание. Ср.: «бизнес-идея», но
>   «бизнесмен».

Но общего правила для всех случаев пока действительно нет...

> У меня еще вопрос: вы понятно объяснили, почему флеш-карта пишется с
>   дефисом,а флешмоб слитно. А как же быть тогда с концепт-каром и
>   спорткаром? Правило начинает действовать прямо наоборот? Не понимаю...

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://pda.gramota.ru/?action=buro&s=%20240527#/page/1)

> Слитное или дефисное написание сложных существительных, недавно
>   заимствованных языком, проверяется в словарном порядке. Есть
>   определенные закономерности, которые охватывают значительную часть
>   подобных слов. На слово концепт-кар эти закономерности не
>   распространяются.

Comment: А какая сила кроме дефиса способна превратить аббревиатуру или слово на латыни в русское определение? Окончание ведь не приделать. Если в английском, из которого перенесён такой порядок слов, предпозиции слова достаточно для трактовки как определения, то в русском - нет: в имеющемся примере с успехом можно разглядеть "отдел Android" с трактовкой второго слова как названия отдела (при латинице кавычки не требуются).

Comment: Саша, про превращения ничего не знаю - практик мы. ))) Я читаю как "отдел андроидной разработки", т. е . отдел какой-то разработки, и десятое дело - какой.

Comment: Не могли бы более развёрнуто пояснить разницу между «определениями, стоящими впереди определяемого слова» и «приложениями»? Можно на конкретных примерах: HTML-страница, онлайн-вьювер, fuzzy поиск, pdf файлы. Так и не понял, где в этих терминах писать раздельно, а где ставить дефис. Спасибо.

Comment: В приведённых Вами примерах дефис должен быть везде: *fuzzy-поиск, pdf-файлы*.