# Точка перед расширениями файлов в составных словах

Tags: компьютеры

Привет с сайта программистов Stack Overflow. Файлы на компьютере имеют расширения, например, ".pdf", ".mp3" или ".jpg". Проставляется ли точка перед расширениями в словах "pdf-файлы", "mp3 файлы", и какими правилами или нормами русского языка это регламентировано? Нужен ли дефис — другой вопрос, пытаюсь разобраться в [**этом**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/421022/180507) ответе. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В предпозиции (**mp3-файл**, **pdf-файл**) дефис нужен по тем же причинам, что и в составных словах словах типа "γ-излучение": первая часть такого слова выполняет функцию определения (какой файл?), которое не может выполнять грамматическую функцию самостоятельного прилагательного, не имея соотв. окончания (такое возможно лишь в просторечном варианте "mp3-шный" и т. п.). Поэтому данный элемент должен быть составе общего слова (слитное написание здесь не проходит уже из-за различия алфавитов). А поскольку *ни одно слово в русском не начинается с точки,* вопрос о её присутствии отпадает независимо от того, приписывать ли её условно расширению. Раздельное написание типа файла по расширению возможно при постпозиции данного элемента, это "**файл** (**типа**) PDF/pdf".

Comment: О точках понял, спасибо. А вот насчёт дефисов запутался. Ср. `дефис нужен по тем же причинам, что и в составных словах словах типа "γ-излучение": первая часть такого слова выполняет функцию определения` и  [`... «Отдел Android разработки» в дефисах не нуждаются, потому что iOS и Android - определения, стоящие впереди определяемого слова`](http://rus.stackexchange.com/a/421022/180507). Спасибо.

Comment: Я в своё время не согласился с тем ответом из другой темы: иностранное слово, написанное символами иного алфавита, не может самостоятельно выполнять функцию определения в русском предложении, поскольку его не изменить под нужную для этого часть речи. Аналогичный случай с непереведённым определением  в кириллице (без адаптации окончания): компакт-диск (= компактный диск).

Comment: То есть по Вашему мнению «отдел Android разработки» равно как и другие примеры из той темы пишутся через дефис? Да, и не могли бы (лучше прямо в ответе) привести ссылки на правила/нормы русского языка, подтверждающие правоту Ваших слов? Как и [**здесь**](http://rus.stackexchange.com/a/423698/180507). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Точка не нужна. В данном случае обозначение расширения файла имеет ввиду тип файла. Например, "mp3 файлы" подразумевают собой "аудио файлы". Что касается дефиса, то тут вопрос спорный. На мой взгляд он тоже не обязателен.

Answer (score 1):

Точка не нужна. но не потому, что ни одно слово не начинается с точки (если "слово" в кавычках, то запросто), а потому, что точка в расширение не входит.

Дефис нужен. pdf - это по сути дела определение, в обратном порядке дефиса бы не было. Что касается android, то тут в комментариях явно на сомнительный источник ссылка процитирована, я вообще не понимаю подобной формулировки.

Тут такая вещь, дефис ставится, когда порядок слов меняет смысл.
Отдел разработки Android - это ж совсем другое, это некий отдел фирмы Android, а не подразделение, занимающееся разработкой под android.