# ЛеБрон (Джеймс) и прочие имена с заглавной буквой в середине

Tags: английский-язык, ономастика

Некоторые имена и фамилии в английском языке содержат заглавную букву внутри. Например, ДеМар ДеРозан, ЛаДайниан Томлинсон, ЛаШон Мерритт. Допускается ли при их переводе на русский использовать заглавную букву в середине имени? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, так нельзя - в середине русских слов не бывает заглавных букв. Вспомним, что такого вопроса раньше не возникало по отношению к ирландским и шотландским фамилиям (McCartney - Маккартни и многие другие известные). Сейчас с распространением любительских переводов можно часто встретить ошибку даже в таких фамилиях. Грешат подобными ошибками и многие журналисты, без достаточных оснований берущие на себя ответственность за перевод собственных имён, например китайских или испанских через английский, вместо использования системы практической транскрипции на русский, которую почти для каждого языка можно найти в википедии (разобраться с этим несложно).